# gem installed, can't import bourbon

Tags: node.js, rubygems, sass, bourbon

I cloned the repo https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost for (a nodejs) Ghost blogging platform and followed the instructions for set up. When I ran `grunt` I got this error

```
Running "sass:compress" (sass) task
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon/_bourbon.
              Load paths:
                /Users/m/Sites/Ghost
                /Users/m/Sites/Ghost/core/client/assets/sass
        on line 22 of ./core/client/assets/sass/modules/mixins.scss
        from line 10 of ./core/client/assets/sass/screen.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I found a blog post http://www.bearfruit.org/2013/10/19/quick-tip-for-getting-the-ghost-blogging-platform-running-locally/ where someone had a similar error that was solved by running

```
 gem install sass bourbon
```

However, that hasn't fixed the problem for me. While I can run `grunt --force`, there are problems with the css that I'm guessing would be solved if it could find the files it's looking for.

In mixin.css file referred to in the error message, it has this

```
// Bourbon - http://bourbon.io/
@import "bourbon/_bourbon";
$rounded: 2px;
$shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0 1px 5px;
$default-transition-duration: 0.3s;
```

However, there's no bourbon folder of any kind in the ghost repo. I'm wondering if it's supposed to import from the installed gem, if so it's not working.

Can you suggest what I might do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not there (for whatever reason), I'd recommend manually installing bourbon. If the gem installs successfully to your system, you can `cd` to your sass directory and run `bourbon install`. That should give you what you need.